# Pyspark: Is it best practice to call .toJSON() on a large dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a large dataframe and I need to convert each row into a JSON and then do 'some processing' on each resulting JSON msg.
The easiest approach seems to be to call .toJSON() on dataframe, collect the result and loop over the result to do the processing on each iteration.
But is calling .toJSON() on large dataframe a scalable approach?
If not, what is the best way I can convert each row in a dataframe to a JSON?

Comment: I am exploring the use of UDF and the point I am stuck at is: the dataframe will be dymanic (I dont know the number of columns, datatypes, etc), so I need to pass the whole Row() object to the UDF and all the examples that I see take only specific columns and passes it to UDF. Is there an example ou can point me to which passes whole Row() to UDF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to use `to_json` method as which is scalable and don't have to use the udf.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.select(to_json(struct(df.columns)))
```

Comment: Could you please explain how is it more scalable and what the difference is between ```to_json``` and ```df.toJSON()```?